# Connecting to Heroku clearDB mySql

Tags: java, mysql, heroku

I'm dabbling with Heroku and managed to deploy a simple app. I added a ClearDB MySQL database instance that lives here:

```
mysql://[user]:[password]@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net
```

I'm trying to connect to it using "dbforge for mysql" but I'm not sure if this is possible. Anyone know if this would be possible? Below shows what the dbforge connection interface looks like as well as the error I get while trying to connect.

[image]

Comment: I think you posted your database's username and password public. Please reset those credentials or destroy and recreate the add-on. For instructions see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb

Comment: yep thanks, I reset the pword, wasn't too concerned about security for now, just trying to get this up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshot you show, the port is `1`, which is incorrect. Check your `DATABASE_URL` to get the correct port or try `3306`, which is the default MySQL port.

In addition, you may need to download and configure the [SSL certificates](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#using-ssl-with-other-heroku-supported-languages-and-frameworks).

Comment: Well your certainly correct about the default port I believe, instead of the above error message I'm now getting "Access denied for user xxx@ipxxx.internal (using password: YES). I guess I might need to setup the SSL certs as well. I'm positive my username and pword are correct, I'll let ya know how things go once I figure out the SSL part. Also epic profile by the way :)

Comment: Was finally able to connect. The main problem appears to be copy/pasting the long encrypted pword into the password field in dbforge, maybe it doesn't support copy/pasted passwords or something I guess. Problem solved, thanks man!